# Find dates older than 2 days and replace it in a variable - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

From below **data** variable, i need to find dates older than 2 days(from the current date) and then replace it with some pattern, can anyone please help.

Example below-

```
# Today is 04-01-2020
data = """
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>03-28-2020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td>03-31-2020</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>qrs</td>
        <td>03-29-2020</td>
    </tr>"""
```

Expected output should be-

```
data = """
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td><font color="#ff0000">03-28-2020</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td>03-31-2020</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>qrs</td>
        <td><b><font color="#ff0000">03-29-2020</font></b></td>

    </tr>"""
```

Comment: What have you tried? what didnt work? have you looked at the datetime module to parse your string date into a date object?

Comment: Yes, i was trying something like this but it  did not worked

`datelimit = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)

for i in data:
    j = datetime.strptime(i,  "%m-%d-%y")
    if j < datelimit:
        print (j.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))`

Comment: @NishaBudakoti Please edit that into your answer then to make it eaiser to follow.

Comment: Also why is the first date wrapped in a font tag but not a bold tag, yet the third date is wrapped in a font and a bold tag? whats the logic for a bold tag?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a full and valid html doc you could use beautiful soup to parse the html, here i am selecting the td tags and then every second tag since these are the dates. If your html is more complicated than this then you can change the selection criteria.

So i then have a list of references to the td tags. I take the date value and make a date object. I then compare it to now and if its more than two days then i need to update it.

to update it i create a font tag and set its string as the date string, i then remove the date string form the td tag. I then create a bold tag and attach the font tag to it then attach the bold tag to the td tag.

```py
import bs4 as bs
from datetime import datetime
data = """
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>03-28-2020</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>efg</td>
            <td>03-31-2020</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>qrs</td>
            <td>03-29-2020</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(data, features="lxml")
for element in soup.select('td')[1::2]:
    element_date = datetime.strptime(element.string, "%m-%d-%Y")
    if (datetime.now() - element_date).days > 2:
        font = soup.new_tag("font", attrs={'color': '#ff0000'})
        font.string = element.string
        element.string=""
        bold = soup.new_tag("b")
        bold.append(font)
        element.append(bold)
print(soup)
```

**OUTPUT**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td><b><font color="#ff0000">03-28-2020</font></b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>efg</td>
            <td>03-31-2020</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>qrs</td>
            <td><b><font color="#ff0000">03-29-2020</font></b></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe a more generic approach (with indices of `td`s  not known) could look at **all** `td`s but try/except a `ValueError` when trying to parse a date within `td.string`. That's in case OP has different HTML outputs to parse.

Comment: I think you don't need to modify OP's input `data` (besides the typo for first date) with html/body containers I guess. `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')` works anyway.

Comment: @Arnaud, yeah sure, i was just using a full and complete example for the OP to see.

Comment: This resolves the issue but can this be done without using Beautiful soup?

Comment: Can anyone please help?